# bash, xmlstarlet to extract two nodes

Tags: bash, macos, sed, kml, xmlstarlet

So, I'm trying to extract some geo data from a KML file. Everything that I see suggests that I could use xmlstarlet in bash. I'm trying to get a CSV file from this (representative) part of sample data (modified earlier to be single line):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
     xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Placemark>
      <open>1</open>
      <gx:Track>
        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
        <when>2015-12-24T18:20:57Z</when>
        <gx:coord>-87.2788204 36.5984675 0</gx:coord>
        <when>2015-12-24T18:20:42Z</when>
        <gx:coord>-87.2784049 36.597298699999996  0</gx:coord>
      </gx:Track>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

That reads:

```
2015-12-24 18:20:57 -87.2788204 36.5984675 0
2015-12-24 18:20:42 -87.2784049 36.597298699999996 0
```

After a little processing with sed (OSX Sierra).

Using the following, I can extract the "gx:coord" node, but the same doesn't apply to the "when" node (why?):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//gx:coord' -v . -n <in.kml > out.csv
```

After trying to piece together rudimentary solutions with multiple sed iterations, I am back to this as the solution that would work consistently, cleanly and yield the best result (xmlstarlet to yield the "when" and "gx:coord" data... I'm unfamiliar with XLST). Suggestions on the command or steps to make this happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `when` is in the default namespace `http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2`.

Try binding a prefix to the namespace (with `-N`).

Example...

```
xmlstarlet sel -N kml='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' -t -m '//gx:coord' -v "concat(preceding-sibling::kml:when[1],' ',.)" -n in.kml
```

Output...

```
2015-12-24T18:20:57Z -87.2788204 36.5984675 0
2015-12-24T18:20:42Z -87.2784049 36.597298699999996  0
```

I just noticed that you're also trying to do some string manipulation on `when`. It can get ugly on the command line, so I'd prefer XSLT, but here's an option...

```
xmlstarlet sel -N kml='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' -t -m '//gx:coord' -v "concat(translate(preceding-sibling::kml:when[1],'TZ','  '),.)" -n in.kml
```

Output...

```
2015-12-24 18:20:57 -87.2788204 36.5984675 0
2015-12-24 18:20:42 -87.2784049 36.597298699999996  0
```